# How to add Proxy to Scrapy and Selenium Script

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to add a proxy to my script.

How do I have to do it? Do I have to use Selenium or Scrapy for it?

I think that Scrapy is making the initial request, so it would make sense to use scrapy for it. But what exactly do I have to do?

Can you recommend any proxylist which works quite reliable?

This is my current script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

import re
import csv
from time import sleep

class PostsSpider(Spider):
    name = 'posts'
    allowed_domains = ['xyz']
    start_urls = ('xyz',)

    def parse(self, response):
        with open("urls.txt", "rt") as f:
            start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
            for url in start_urls:
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
                self.driver.get(url)

                try:
                    self.driver.find_element_by_id('currentTab').click()
                    sleep(3)
                    self.logger.info('Sleeping for 5 sec.')
                    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_blog-menu"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[3]').click()
                    sleep(7)
                    self.logger.info('Sleeping for 7 sec.')
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    self.logger.info('Blog does not exist anymore')

                while True:                 
                    try:
                        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id('last_item')
                        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight-5);", element)
                        sleep(3)
                        self.driver.find_element_by_id('last_item').click()
                        sleep(7)


                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        self.logger.info('No more tipps')                       
                        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
                        allposts = sel.xpath('//*[@class="block media _feedPick feed-pick"]')

                        for post in allposts:
                            username = post.xpath('.//div[@class="col-sm-7 col-lg-6 no-padding"]/a/@title').extract()
                            publish_date = post.xpath('.//*[@class="bet-age text-muted"]/text()').extract()

                            yield {'Username': username,
                                'Publish date': publish_date}
                        self.driver.close()
                        break
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables.

You could set them in your environment before starting your script, or maybe add this at the beginning of your script:

```py
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://my/proxy'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://my/proxy'
```

For a list of publicly available proxy, you will find a ton if you just search in Google.

Answer (score 0):

You should read Scrapy [ProxyMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy) to explore it to best. Ways of using mentioned proxies are also mentioned in it